# Should a user be logged in after resetting their password?

Tags: forms, login, password, security, workflow

Lets assume following flow:

1. I want to log in
2. I don't remember password
3. I click on the "forgot my password" link *(email is dispatched)*
4. I check my inbox and click on the link
5. I type in a new password
6. Done

Why, after performing these steps, am I not logged in but instead presented with log-on screen? If we refer back to 1. then it seems obvious that I would like to log in.

**Are there any use cases when someone would like to change their password via "forgot my password" link and then not log in?** Unless I'm missing something obvious, the intention is clear and identity was established by using reset link from email.

Please tell what are your thoughts, please tell whether the user should be logged in after resetting the password?

Related: [Should confirm email links autologin if the user is not logged in?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/should-confirm-email-links-autologin-if-the-user-is-not-logged-in) *(my answer would be yes)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should confirm email links autologin if the user is not logged in?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/should-confirm-email-links-autologin-if-the-user-is-not-logged-in)

Comment: I don't see the problem. Remember, they are users and can do whatever they like and not _only_ the steps you pave out for them. You have to be flexible. Why wouldn't you like when somebody doesn't log in immediately after requesting a new password? Put a time limit on the link, or a amount of requests/day if you like.

Comment: As you've suggested, there is a very closely related question to this one. What is it that differs your question from that one, as they appear to be both covering the same ground?

Comment: I agree that these two are closely related. Reason for differentiating - here are two possible workflows: **1)** I just want create an account and access it later **2)** As an online marketeer I would like to receive their onboarding emails as reference material. Remember: *users and can do whatever they like* (via @Dirk)

Comment: To collect user data especially, you want to make it easy on your user while keeping a high standard security level (if it fits the overall expectation of the behavior of the site; e.g. are returning users are automatically logged in again). Then, depending on your systems' statistics/database (in your question, if users come back to complete the lost password), if it's worthwhile investigating specific drop-out moments.

Comment: I think this question should also be asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/ since it has security implications as well. Having the question on both the UX and security boards would let us see the issue from both perspectives.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105124/why-should-you-redirect-the-user-to-a-login-page-after-a-password-reset

Answer (score 50):

**No.** While it seems to be annoying, I see four problems with not having to enter the login information again:

1. I will remember my new password better if I have to type it once more. (I keep forgetting my new e-banking password because I don't have to re-enter it, and I of course don't store it in the browser.)
2. If I want to store the password, the browser PW manager is sometimes confused by the PW change and is not able to treat it properly; this is not the case when I enter a different PW into the standard login form
3. Having to use the password is the best way to make oneself sure that the password has been really changed.
4. (security) IMHO it's better when a user logs in only by **LOG IN** button and never by anything else like **CHANGE PASSWORD** button.

Comment: I would give three -1 for the options 1, 2 and 4, as I completely disagree, but the 3rd option is so brilliant, that in summary I give +1 :)

Comment: @Voitcus They all _are_ my opinions. However, as well, I was unhappy about 2 "yes" answers being here with a "no" answer missing that would state the counter-arguments.

Comment: The big security concern here is if the reset isn't handled properly. Let's say for instance if the key used in the URL isn't removed, then if someone got that key from your email, browser cache, or even server log files then they wouldn't need your password to log in. It probably doesn't have much impact on the original question, but just a note for the security.

Comment: +1 for the No. I'd add: 5. I may want to change my password without having to then logout (ie, I'm not always wanting to use the new password and log with it right away...)

Comment: @Chris: I believe that key-reset URL's should be "only useable once" ? Otherwise, as you said, someone could maybe re-use it later...

Comment: @OlivierDulac I suppose my point is that as a user, how could you know that the key is actually only one time use. Well trying it again, but how could you reassure the user through better UX? And maybe one of the two approaches here better communicates that.

Comment: None of these reasons are good reasons for the user to have to deal with this. 1 is nonsense on a number of levels, 2 is something users shouldn't have to deal with, 3 can be handled much better by just giving proper feedback, and 4 I just totally don't get.

Comment: +1 primarily for #2, I log out then back in just to get Firefox to update it correctly

Comment: +1 for 2 and 4 +100 for 3 I usually log out immediately to check I can log in

Comment: @Chris: Being logged in would be a pretty clear indicator that the process worked.  I think the biggest issue is that browsers aren't apt to remember the password properly if the user doesn't type it into the log-in form.  On the other hand, some people who use a site only rarely and would prefer to have the site validate them via text message or email every time they want to log in without having to worry about creating or storing a secure password might be better served by having a means of avoiding the set-password step altogether.

Comment: I started reading and thought "+1 for 1, I thought exactly the same", and it's even more helpful if one uses completely different passwords for different sites. Then I read 2 and thought "+1 for 2, this happens to me a lot". Then 3 remembered me of my university's web services which are very confusing and I'm never sure whether I reset the password of the email or the other services (I kept trying to log in to the webmail with the password I had reset for the other services). I only disagree with 4, but this is a very well thought out answer, wish I could +1 again.

Comment: I think the strongest argument for not logging the user in automatically is that he/she might not have gone through the reset password process on the same device that he/she wanted to log in on. A common flow is that the link is demanded on a laptop but the mail with the reset link is then opened on a smartphone. You might not be interested in being logged in on that device.

Comment: Your 2nd point will not be valid if I am not using a web-app/site. Also, users usually do not agree to your 1st point. BUT I totally agree with your 3rd & most importantly 4th point - you just nailed boss!

Comment: to 3rd & 4th point: You can notify user in advance, stating on the top of the form in e.g. subtitle that after they successfully change their password, they will be logged in.

Answer (score 41):

**In my opinion: YES.**

The authentication has been done when the password is reset, so the user could be logged in. And it annoys the hell out of me when after password reset I'm not logged in.

I can't think of any case I wouldn't want to be logged in after resetting password, *why would I even ask for password reset if I don't want to log in*?

Comment: +1 it annoys the hell out of me *(I was wondering if it is only me, glad I'm not alone)*

Comment: +1 I agree it is a bit of a hindrance when completing all the steps and your presented with the log-on screen.

Comment: **Yes** -  If there exists a history where auto re-logging  in has caused significant problems, then I would say **no**.  But the **no** reasons tend to fall in the class of "what is best for me" and not what is convenient for me.  (First Post)

Comment: Atleast having a "change password and log in" choice would be nice improvement on many cases...

Answer (score 9):

**For the vast majority of situations users should be logged in once they have reset their password**.  Essentially, once you've authenticated someone enough for them to change a password, you've also authenticated them enough for them to perform the task that they likely wanted to perform.

There are however some relatively rare situations where this isn't feasible:

- Where you have a username for a system, but it isn't clear which site you need to log into.  For example, if you're an accountant and have a username / password for an online accounting system that you use for many clients.  Often there will be separate domain names for each client such as `client1.accounting.com` and `client2.accounting.com`.  Here resetting your password would apply across all related sites, but it isn't clear which site you should log into.
- If the authentication is handled by a separate system to the the application.  It's not that it wouldn't be good UX to do this, just that it may be a large technical headache, and so not considered worth the cost.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create two buttons "Change password & Login" and "Just change password"?
Having another option doesn't hurt in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is bit controversial. Actually it depends upon the user's perspective of how the user reacts depending upon the situation.

We can explain the situation by using 2 point of views :

1. From user's point of view, it is obvious that he/she may think of **not entering the password again** once he/she changed that. In that case the user may be annoyed and think that re-entering the password will be sheer waste of time. So, it is correct not to enter the password again.
2. From the technical perspective(especially testing point of view), it may happen that the user might have logged in the account few days back using any other device like mobile,tablets etc.

So, once the password is reset, then the user is again prompted for entering the new password so that the confirmation will be sent to the system as the password is changed. Hence it is required to enter the password again.

Answer (score 0):

Enforcing user to re login after changing and resetting password totally disagree with the main point of having the forgot password logic.
for example:

- as a user I don't want to save my password in my mind or anywhere else so I want to use forgot password logic every time I want to login to my account and during that logic I set a totally random password and I don't save it in my mind
- enforcing me to login after setting new password will put me in a cycle to re reset my password and set a new easy to remember password which put my account in risk if 2FA is not on

based on that scenario developers must not ask users to re login after password reset.

Comment: Do you really use the "forgot password logic" to login into site and services? Clearly the design behind this is at least messed up, I mean, call it "login without password", or "login with email" instead... well, my 2 cents.

Comment: this is the reason for having a forgot password logic